# How to filter a list of elements by a list of matching key values?

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, filter

I'm struggling a bit with comparing the key/vals from multiple lists and could use some help. Given a list of `People` with a `firstName` and `age` property, and a separate list of ages, how would I filter the `People` list to return only those with one of the matching ages?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("John", 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Lisa", 54);
        Person p3 = new Person("Mike", 61);
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);

        List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList(25, 54);
        List<Person> specificAges = people.stream().filter(p -> p.age == ages?????)

        System.out.println(specificAges);
    }
}

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String firstName, Integer age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + age;
    }
}
```

Expected Result: `["John 25", "Lisa 54"]`

Comment: `p -> ages.contains(p.age)`

Comment: (with a follow-up `).toList()` at the end).

Comment: It's better to put ages in a HashSet before (new HashSet<>(ages)) to do whole filtering in O(n) time instead of O(n*m)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ages.contains(p.age)` in the lambda function.

```java
List<Person> specificAges = people
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> ages.contains(p.getAge()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I used getter method to get age of each `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

If a *stream* is not a requirement, a *for-loop* would also suffice.

```java
List<Person> specificAges = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person : people) {
    if (ages.contains(person.age)) specificAges.add(person);
}
```

Output

```
[John 25, Lisa 54]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a separate Person class and use the annotations for quick constructor, getter/setter development.

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private Integer age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + age;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code would remain the same. You can either use a stream of for each loop as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For a "less code" solution, make a copy then use `removeIf()`:

```
List<Integer> specificAges = new ArrayList<>(people);
specificAges.removeIf(p -> !ages.contains(p.getAge()));
```

If keeping the original list is not necessary, just:

```
people.removeIf(p -> !ages.contains(p.getAge()));
```